# Can't access global variable using AJAX/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a global variable **var emp_error = 0;**
but when I access emp_error even though it when through **else** (since the tr's bg color changes), emp_error is still 0.
Can someone help me out? So that it won't update the employee ID if it already exists

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo site_url('c_device/check_empId'); ?>",
     data: dataString,
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
              if(data.length == 0){
                   emp_error=0;
              }else{
                   $("#error_"+tr_id).html("Emp id exists");    
                   $("#"+tr_id).css("background-color","red");                  
                   emp_error++;
              }                  
     }
});
```

Comment: here is another SO post link to something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795831/jquery-ajax-local-variable-cant-assign-to-global

Comment: if your var emp_error is instantiated with the value of 0 why do you have the if statement? wouldn't this be enough? `if(data.length){
                   $("#error_"+tr_id).html("Emp id exists");    
                   $("#"+tr_id).css("background-color","red");                  
                   emp_error+=1;
              }`

Comment: Oh and avoid using doing this `your_var++;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Comment: Don't listen Fabio. Nothing bad in ++ operator.

Comment: How and when are you testing the value of `emp_error`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `emp_error` to increment on multiple calls, you need to a) not reset to 0 when it fails, and b) define it outside of the function so `emp_error++` has something to increment if the first call is not empty.

Define the global outside of the function the contains the ajax call.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5h9pL/

If you won't be making multiple calls and actually just want `emp_error` to be set when an employee is found, don't mess with globals at all:

```
      if(data.length == 0){
           emp_error = 0;
      }else{
           $("#error_"+tr_id).html("Emp id exists");    
           $("#"+tr_id).css("background-color","red");                  
           emp_error = 1;
      }
```